# conexion PHP con DBISAM

Tags: php, html, sql, mysql

Desde hace varios días he intentado conectarme a una base de datos DBISAM pero no lo he logrado, descargue e instale el controlador odbc y hago pruebas desde excel y funciona perfecto pero cuando lo intento por PHP me da error, este es el script que estoy utilizando:

```
<?php  
$dsn = '"DRIVER={DBISAM 4 ODBC Driver}; ConnectionType=Local; CatalogName=C:/direccion donde estan las tablas;';
$user = '';
$password = '';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    echo "conexion establecidad";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

este es el error que me aparece:

> Connection failed: could not find driver

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tienes instalado correctamente el [driver](http://www.elevatesoft.com/download?category=dbisam), prueba usando `odbc_exec()` :

```
$db = odbc_connect("DRIVER={DBISAM 4 ODBC Driver};ConnectionType=Local;CatalogName=C:\[path catalogo];","admin","");

$res = odbc_exec($db,"SELECT * FROM [tabla]");
echo odbc_num_rows($res)." Registros!";

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($res)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: tienes razon lo coloque sin querer cuando publique el codigo pero aun asi sigue mi problema.

Comment: como tienes definido ConnectionType=Local , revisa si es correcta la ruta del catalogo, puedo ver como lo defines?

Comment: C:\a2automatroni\a2admin\Empre001\Data esta es la ruto donde estan guardadas las tablas pero aun asi he cambiado por muchas direciones y nada

Comment: Si definiste seguridad, tal vez tienes que añadir "[usuario]","[password]"); es así?

Comment: de igual manera probe con el usuario por defecto que es admin, con y sin contraseña y nada.  http://cnedelcu.blogspot.com/2013/09/access-dbisam-database-with-php-via-odbc.html https://alejandrodotnet.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/accessing-data-using-dbisam-odbc-driver-with-c-net/

Comment: Que versión usas DBISAM 4.2..?

Comment: revisa mi script prueba a ver si te funciona en lugar de crear un new PDO().

Comment: al probar tu script no retorna ningun error pero tampoco me funciona en este caso se queda cargando el navegador como si lo estuviera buscando, ya no encuentro manera de resolver mi problema